# How to copy a Visio shapesheet section between shapes in VBA

Tags: vba, visio, shapesheet

Is there a method available for copying a section out of a shape to another shape using VBA?  I'm specifically trying to copy all the custom properties and user cells from one pagesheet to another page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a simple method to do this. You will have to loop over all the rows in the source sheet and create the same rows in the destination sheet. E.g.:

```
Dim oPageSheet1 As Visio.Shape
Dim oPageSheet2 As Visio.Shape
Dim rowName     As String
Dim i   As Integer

Set oPageSheet1 = Visio.ActiveDocument.Pages.Item(1).PageSheet
Set oPageSheet2 = Visio.ActiveDocument.Pages.Item(2).PageSheet

i = visRowUser

While oPageSheet1.CellsSRCExists(visSectionUser, i, visUserValue, False)
    oPageSheet2.AddNamedRow visSectionUser, oPageSheet1.Section(visSectionUser).Row(i).NameU, 0
    oPageSheet2.Section(visSectionUser).Row(i).Name = oPageSheet1.Section(visSectionUser).Row(i).Name
    oPageSheet2.CellsSRC(visSectionUser, i, visUserValue).FormulaU = oPageSheet1.CellsSRC(visSectionUser, i, visUserValue).FormulaU
    oPageSheet2.CellsSRC(visSectionUser, i, visUserPrompt).FormulaU = oPageSheet1.CellsSRC(visSectionUser, i, visUserPrompt).FormulaU
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

If you have to copy a large number of rows and performance is a consideration you should investigate using [AddRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175231(office.11).aspx) and [SetFormulas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175375(office.11).aspx).